# Trying to get property 'slots' of non-object while accessing data in php

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to pull data from external api using guzzle http. Here is my code

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'api/endpoint/');
$contents = $res->getBody()->getContents();
return $contents->slots; // THIS LINE GIVES ME ERROR. TRYING TO ACCESS THE SLOT.
```

My data structure coming from api looks like this when I just return the `$contents like this return $contents`

[image]

I want to get access of `slots`.

Anyone can help? Thank you,

Comment: have you tried to json_decode? json_decode($contents); then access as array?

Comment: Thanks this works. You can post it as answer :)